# Migrating D3.js report in Power Bi?

Tags: d3.js, reporting-services, report, business-intelligence, powerbi

I have a really nice fancy report written in D3.js and wondering if it possible to include it in Power Bi using Custom visual capability.I can't find too much informations about it as also the level of complexity.

All the best

Vincent

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a custom visual.  Have you seen the custom visual repo? https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/custom-visuals/

Comment: Hi,thanks,yes i did but there is no documentation about integration Js library into it.I am looking for a bit of documentation about it or some tutorial